# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un valor de json?

Tags: c#, json

Obtengo este json desde una api en service layer

```
{
 "odata.metadata": "https://localhost:50000/b1s/v1/$metadata#Items",
"value": [   {
  "odata.etag": "W/\"356A192B7913B04C54574D18C28D46E6395428AB\"",
  "ItemCode": "A001"
}]
}
```

Lo que necesito es obtener el valor de *ItemCode* ya que está dentro de un arreglo, y no entiendo cómo entrar al arreglo de *value* para obtener ese valor y almacenarlo en una variable.

Comment: Con qué lenguaje de programación lo quieres obtener?

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer esto desde C# necesitas deserializar el objeto. Si estas utilizando una libreria para consumir el servicio que te devuelve el JSON, posiblemente esa libreria disponga de algun mecanismo para hacerlo. En caso contrario, con un `string` que contenga el contenido JSON que muestras, lo puedes deserializar utilizando la clase `JsonSerializer` y el metodo `Deserialize<>`. [Este contenido](http://lmatogemssyncmanager/) te puede ser de ayuda.

Es importante notar que para utilizar estas opciones lo mas recomendable es que crees una clase que se corresponda con la estructura del objeto que estas recibiendo. Deserializarias un arreglo de una clase que tiene un atributo "value" que es a su vez un arreglo de una clase que tiene una propiedad "ItemCode".

Comment: Si bien es completa la respuesta, evita responder a preguntas en donde el autor de la misma no haya demostrado sus intentos en resolver el planteamiento. Lee [answer].

Comment: @padaleiana Notada la recomendacion, aunque no considero que esto sea una razon para un voto menos.

Comment: Generalmente suelen hacer eso (no fui yo) cuando se responde a este tipo de preguntas, como si fuese un "voto punitorio".

Answer (score -1):

Si es con javascript puedes probar de esta manera:

```js
let data = [
  {
    "odata.metadata": "https://localhost:50000/b1s/v1/$metadata#Items",
    "value": [{
      "odata.etag": "W/\"356A192B7913B04C54574D18C28D46E6395428AB\"",
      "ItemCode": "A001"
    }]
  }
]


let variable;
data.forEach(val => {
  val.value.forEach(p => {
    variable = p.ItemCode;
  })
})


console.log(variable)
```

Comment: se me habia pasado de que es en c# pero buscare